# How to add a contact from a missed call?

Tags: contacts

Someone just gave me his number with a missed call. I'm trying to create a contact from this missed call but I see it's not possible! By tapping the missed call one second I can send a message, dial IP call, delete, etc, but not create a contact from it. Is there not any way than writing down the number and manually creating a contact and copying the number?

Comment: Which Android version and device are you using? Can you post a screenshot (contact(s) blurred of course) of the missed call in the dialer/phone default app? In my 4.2.1 and 4.4.2 I can easily add the missed call number as a contact by tapping the entry once -> Add to contacts. Alternatively, tapping contact(person) icon before the start of number gives the same option.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this. Long press the number, then chose Edit number before call. You then have the Add to Contacts option, click that and then choose Create new contact.

Comment: does this method applies to all Android devices? Think..... So, you may consider adding relevant device details on which these steps are valid.